# CGDataProviderRefReleaseCallback not being called

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm creating a CGBitmap using the code below, but the `done_callback` function is never called. What am I doing wrong? The bitmap is created correctly but I have no way to free the pixel buffer afterwards. Is it because the CGBitmap is never released?

```
void done_callback(void *info, const void *data, size_t size)
{
    free((void *)data);
    NSLog(@"Done!");
}

static CGImageRef SVG_to_CGImage(char const *svg, int width, int height)
{
    using namespace lunasvg;
    
    auto doc = Document::loadFromData(svg);
    if(doc.get() == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    
    auto bmp = doc->renderToBitmap(width, height);
    if(!bmp.valid()) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    
    UInt32 *pixels = (UInt32 *)malloc(width * height * 4);

    // rearrange the BGRA to RGBA
    for(int y=0; y<height; ++y) {
        UInt32 *s = (UInt32 *)(bmp.data() + y * width * 4);
        UInt32 *d = pixels + y * width;
        for(int x=0; x<width; ++x) {
            UInt32 argb = *s++;
            UInt32 a = argb & 0xff000000;
            UInt32 r = (argb & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            UInt32 g = argb & 0xff00;
            UInt32 b = (argb & 0xff) << 16;
            *d++ = a | r | g | b;
        }
    }
    
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, pixels, width * height * 4, done_callback);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
    return CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, 4 * width, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
}
```

Comment: From the documentation of `CGDataProviderCreateWithData`: "Return Value: A new data provider. You are responsible for releasing this object using CGDataProviderRelease". When is the returned image released? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: I guess I'm confused about whether the CGDataProviderRef is retained by CGImageCreate and whether I can release it immediately and then... what, CGImageCreate releases it when its done with it? Sorry, total MacOS/Objective-C newbie here

Comment: How is "The provider is retained; on return, you may safely release it." confusing? Maybe this helps: [Basic Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1).